# Is it safe to have an open account creation endpoint?

Tags: spring, account

I want to create a webpage which allows people to create an account on our spring server. My naive implementation would look like this:

- Create an endpoint 'createaccount' where a website can perform a post method (email & password is sent to it)
- Create an account creation form (www.myurl.com/createaccount.html)
- When a user fills out email and password on this site and clicks submit, the data gets stored inside a database with a flag indicating that the user hasnt been confirmed yet, at the same point an email is sent to his mail with an activation link
- When he clicks this link, the user gets confirmed

Since im no expert in web security, I need to know if

- It is safe to have an unprotected endpoint for this task
- There is a better alternative to let users create accounts

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a security expert, but here are the risks that I can think of:

- Someone can write a script that automates the creation of accounts on your system. These accounts can be used to get access to secured endpoints.
- Someone can write a script that enumerates email addresses and uses your endpoint to determine whether or not an email address exists on your system.

Some things that people do in this case:

- Captcha, to prevent scripts from signing up
- Invite-only enrollment: New accounts can only be created by existing users of the system, or perhaps only by admin users.

If there's not a lot of traffic to the site, then maybe the chance of someone exploiting the endpoint isn't as great as there would be to a high-profile site.